# icon sizes android, most common padding/size facebook/youtube

Tags: android, facebook, youtube, android-icons, android-launcher

So for the different screen sizes, you have the following sizes for the launcher icons:

> ldpi (240 x 320px) icon 36x36, 120dpi
>
> mdpi (320 x 480px) icon 48x48, 160dpi
>
> hdpi (480 x 800px) icon 72x72, 240dpi
>
> xhdpi (720 x 1280px) icon 96x96, 320dpi
>
> (Google Play 512x512)

If you use those sizes without padding, I've noticed that the icons are bigger than for example the ones youtube and facebook use. Does anyone know the size of those icons (or the padding)?

Even better, can I download somewhere templates with the same sizes, such as http://developer.android.com/shareables/icon_templates-v4.0.zip?

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html mentions a small 4px padding for xhdpi icons (96x96 -> 88x88) which is exactly what the template you linked does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best example I have seen is [foursquare's open source android version](https://code.google.com/p/foursquared/source/browse/#hg/main/res%253Fstate%253Dclosed). If you download the source you'll be able to browse through the `res/drawable-xxx` folders and see how they handle various cases with their icons that appear to be approximately the same size as, say, facebook's android icons (maybe a pixel or two more padding).

I recommend checking out this project and simply examining their files in your photo editor of choice.

Just as a note: foursquare is no longer open sourcing their app (and hasn't for some time now...), so the code found at the above repo may be a little stale.